# How to fix OnItemClickListener on ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, onitemclicklistener, listview-adapter

This is java class MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mhn.intercoapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.mhn.intercoapp.Adapters.EmployeeDirAdapter;
import com.example.mhn.intercoapp.static_class.EmployeeDir;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EmployeeDirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    ImageView back_button;
    EmployeeDir obj;
    ArrayList <EmployeeDir> empDir ;
    EmployeeDirAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_employee_directory);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_emp_directory_xml);
        back_button = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back_button_header_emp_directory_activity_xml);
        obj = new EmployeeDir();
        empDir = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new EmployeeDirAdapter(getApplicationContext(),empDir);

        back_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        obj.setEmp_name("Hafiz Sadique Umar");
        obj.setEmp_email("hsu@gmail.com");
        obj.setEmp_contact_num("+923045607057");
        empDir.add(obj);
        empDir.add(obj);
        empDir.add(obj);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                    long arg3)
            {
                String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DoneActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
                // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
            }
        });


    }
}
```

This is activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EmployeeDirectoryActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relatice_layout_header_emp_directory_activity_xml"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_height="56dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/back_button_header_emp_directory_activity_xml"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:src="@drawable/back_arrow_header"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Employee Directory"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/listView_emp_directory_xml"
        android:layout_below="@id/relatice_layout_header_emp_directory_activity_xml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

This is Adapter

```
package com.example.mhn.intercoapp.Adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.text.util.Linkify;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.mhn.intercoapp.MainActivity;
import com.example.mhn.intercoapp.R;
import com.example.mhn.intercoapp.static_class.EmployeeDir;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class EmployeeDirAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ArrayList<EmployeeDir> menuData=new ArrayList<>();

    public EmployeeDirAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EmployeeDir>EmpDir)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuData=EmpDir;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return menuData.get(i);
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolderEmpDir holder;
        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolderEmpDir();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.emp_directory_list_row_layout, parent, false);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout);
            holder.email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.email_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout);
            holder.phone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.phone);
            holder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.emp_pic_emp_directory_list_row_layout);
            holder.viewButton = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_button_emp_dir_list_row_layout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolderEmpDir) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(menuData.get(position).getEmp_name());
        holder.email.setText(menuData.get(position).getEmp_email());
        holder.phone.setText(menuData.get(position).getEmp_contact_num());
        //Linkify.addLinks(holder.email,Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES);
        //Linkify.addLinks(holder.phone,Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
        holder.pic.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_sign_up);

        holder.viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            }
        });
        //downloadImage(position,holder);
        return convertView;
    }


//    private void downloadImage(int position,ViewHolderShowAllBooking holder)
//    {
//        Picasso.with(context)
//                .load("http://www.efefoundation.net/inklink/uploads/artist/"+menuData.get(position).getArtistId()+".jpg")
//                .fit() // will explain later
//                .into(holder.profile);
//    }


    static class ViewHolderEmpDir
    {
        TextView name;
        TextView email;
        TextView phone;
        ImageView pic;
        ImageView viewButton;
    }
}
```

This is list_row_layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/emp_pic_emp_directory_list_row_layout"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user_sign_up"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_weight="3">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Husnain"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/name_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:autoLink="phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="***********"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/name_textView_emp_directory_list_row_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="mhn786@gmail.com"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view_button_emp_dir_list_row_layout"
        android:src="@drawable/view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I apply OnItemClickListener it does not do any action like intent inside the func not called. I tried toast too but nothing shown on clicking the listView Items. 
I also tried OnItemSlectedListener , it also not worked for me. 
What is the problem here with this code. ?

Comment: On which one do you want the action to be performed ? on the button or the row? As OnItemClickListener would take the click event of the whole row where as if you want to make click event on view in the list inflated prefer using an interface and make the action implemented on the activity. Its observed that though you have mentioned it in intent but you have'nt started the activity. Also it is advised you make use activity's context instead of using  getApplicationContext to avoid leaks.

Comment: U getting elements in listview

Comment: have you tried adding `focusable = false` to your `ImageViews` in `row layout`

Comment: @DonnyDominic I want to do action on whole item click.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `android:clickable="true"` in your `ListView` could be overriding all of click events of its child views, you should probably remove it:

```
<ListView
    android:clickable="true" <!-- Remove this attribute -->
    android:id="@+id/listView_emp_directory_xml"
    android:layout_below="@id/relatice_layout_header_emp_directory_activity_xml"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: I do but nothing happend

Comment: Are you able to scroll the list?

Comment: @MuhammadHusnainNaseer What about if you change `adapter = new EmployeeDirAdapter(getApplicationContext(),empDir);` to `adapter = new EmployeeDirAdapter(getActivity(),empDir);?`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Every One. Issue was with autolink on email and phone, I make their focusable=false but nothing happened.Then I remove it and guess what? Clicklistener also starts working.